# String theory hilbert space - Gas of free gravitons

Tags: hilbert-space, entropy, string-theory, research-level, ads-cft

I am trying to understand the arguments given in [MAGOO](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9905111) in chapter 3.4.1(Hilbert Space of String Theory). The authors give descriptions of the Hilbert space of String Theory when we consider our theory in different energy regimes. There are 4 such regimes. Since each regime is enough material for one question I will spread this in 4 different questions. Let's start here with the first regime where we have

1: **Gas of Free Gravitons($E\ll m_s$)**

In this low energy regime we can approxiamate the states of our Hilbert space by the Fock space of gravitons in $AdS_5\times S^5$. Then the states are the stationary wave solutions as shown in section 2.2.2 which are the solutions of the scalar KG-equation in $AdS_{p+2}$
$$
\phi=e^{i\omega\tau}G(\theta)Y_l(\Omega_p)
$$
with $G(\theta)=(\sin\theta)^l(\cos\theta)^{\lambda_{\pm}} \;_2F_1(a,b,c;\sin\theta)$ and
$$
a=\frac{1}{2}(l+\lambda_{\pm}-\omega R)\\
b=\frac{1}{2}(l+\lambda_{\pm}+\omega R)\\
c=l+\frac{1}{2}(p+1)
$$

and
$$
\lambda_\pm=\frac{1}{2}(p+1)\pm\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{(p+1)^2+4(mR)^2}
$$
Then they argue that stationary modes are quantised "in the unit set by R" so they view the supergravity particles as confined in a box of size R(the curvature radius). Why are they confined in this box of size R?

I understand that I'm probably missing something in the derivation of this, but the next point is very confusing to me.

They also state the entropy, as a function of density of states
$$
S(E)\sim(ER)^\frac{9}{10}
$$
where did this come from? How is this entropy calculated(estimated?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the purposes of thermodynamics, you can treat the propagating modes of the graviton (and superpartners) as independent scalar fields satisfying
\begin{equation}
\nabla_\mu \nabla^\mu \phi + \xi R \phi = 0.
\end{equation}

And then there's a very quick and dirty way to verify that $AdS_{d + 1}$ will behave like a box. Instead of a minimally coupled scalar with $\xi = 0$, you can consider a *conformally coupled* scalar with $\xi = \frac{d - 1}{4d}$. This will allow you to perform a Weyl rescaling on the metric to get
\begin{align}
&ds^2 = -\left ( 1 + \frac{r^2}{R^2} \right ) dt^2 + \left ( 1 + \frac{r^2}{R^2} \right )^{-1} dr^2 + r^2 d\Omega_{d - 1}^2 \\
\mapsto \;\; &ds^2 = -dt^2 + \left ( 1 + \frac{r^2}{R^2} \right )^{-2} dr^2 + \left ( 1 + \frac{r^2}{R^2} \right )^{-1} r^2 d\Omega_{d - 1}^2.
\end{align}
We can now get an effective volume of global $AdS_5$ as
\begin{align}
V &= \int \sqrt{g} \, dr \, d\Omega_3 \\
&= \mathrm{Vol}(S^3) \int_0^\infty \left ( 1 + \frac{r^2}{R^2} \right )^{-5/2} r^3 dr \\
&= \frac{2}{3} \mathrm{Vol}(S^3) R^4.
\end{align}
In the present problem there should of course be another piece due to the $S^5$.

To proceed with analyzing a gas of free fields, we know that for a fermion, there can be 0 or 1 quanta with momentum $p$ so we get a single mode partition function of $Z(p) = 1 + e^{-\beta |p|}$. For a boson, there can be arbitrarily many excitations so
\begin{equation}
Z(p) = 1 + e^{-\beta |p|} + e^{-2\beta |p|} + \dots = (1 - e^{-\beta |p|})^{-1}.
\end{equation}
To get the log of the full partition function, we sum over all modes, leading to
\begin{align}
\log Z &= \sum_p \log Z(p) \\
&\approx \int | \log (1 \pm e^{-\beta |p|}) | \frac{V d^d p}{(2\pi)^d} \\
&= \frac{V}{(2\pi \beta)^d} \Gamma(d) \mathrm{Vol}(S^{d - 1}) \zeta^{\pm}(d + 1).
\end{align}
In the last step, we have Taylor expanded the log and integrated term by term. The answer involves the Riemann zeta function $\zeta^-$ for bosons and the so called alternating zeta function $\zeta^+$ for fermions. Knowing that the free energy is
\begin{equation}
F = E - TS = -T \log Z,
\end{equation}
the formula for the entropy now follows from $S = - \frac{\partial F}{\partial T}$. However, the above is overkill if we aren't interested in the precise prefactor.

The slick way to find that $S \sim E^{d/(d + 1)}$ (so $E^{9/10}$ in $9 + 1$ dimensions) is to use scale invariance. Gravitons are massless and cannot introduce a scale beyond the $AdS$ radisu $R$. Therefore at temperatures much larger than $R^{-1}$ (but still much smaller than the string scale), entropy must be extensive. But entropy is a dimensionless quantity so the only way to achieve this is to have
\begin{equation}
S \sim V T^d.
\end{equation}
The same goes for internal energy but that needs to have one more power of temperature
\begin{equation}
E \sim V T^{d + 1}.
\end{equation}
Eliminating $T$ then yields $S$ in terms of $E$. As an aside, a free theory is not the only case where it's possible to determine the prefactor. Another is a 2d conformal field theory where modular invariance leads to the Cardy formula for the density of states.

Comment: Thank you very much! So the derivation of the partition function is not used? Essentially we use dimensional analysis?

Comment: Yes. The last of the four regimes ($E^{3/4}$ for SYM theory in 3 + 1 dimensions) can be argued in the same way. So it is then a nice check that MAGOO recovers this by considering large black holes.

Answer (score 1):

AdS behaves like a box, since the boundaries at infinity can be reached in a finite amount of time. See for instance [Does one observe light reach infinity in finite time in AdS spacetime?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/556998/does-one-observe-light-reach-infinity-in-finite-time-in-ads-spacetime)

Regarding the entropy, you should look into how to derive the entropy of an ideal gas in 10D. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microcanonical_ensemble#Ideal_gas) for a calculation in 3D in the microcanonical ensemble.

Comment: I understand that lightrays can be reflected at finite time, even though AdS can be thought of as an infinite box but why should it have size R?

Comment: It is explained in 2.2.2. By imposing that the energy-momentum flux of a scalar field through the boundary is zero you get 2.41, which show you that the wave are quantised in the unit set by R: $$ w = w_0 + 2n/R $$

Comment: R is also the only scale in AdS, so it has to be expected that the quantisation comes in units or R.

Comment: Thank you for your remarks. Would it be possible to add the derivation of the entropy?