# Gravitational backreaction in AdS/CFT

Tags: general-relativity, ads-cft, qft-in-curved-spacetime

When we add a scalar field into AdS space time, under which limit can we ignore the gravitational back reaction? In the case of massless scalar, can we totally ignore the backreation to the background geometry?

Comment: AdS / CFT should be learned after the lesson that all energy curves spacetime whether or not it's mass.

Comment: Thanks Connor, yes, because the stress tensor of the massless scalar field is non zero, however, i still want to understand how one can neglect this change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of this comes from reading "lore" and working backwards but hopefully it's not too imprecise.

Solving for the cosmological constant in terms of the $AdS_{d + 1}$ length $L$, Einstein's equations read
\begin{align}
G_{\mu\nu} - \frac{d(d - 1)}{2L^2} g_{\mu\nu} = 8\pi G T_{\mu\nu}.
\end{align}
Based on this, we want all components of the stress tensor to be less than $\frac{1}{L^2 G}$ so that most of the curvature does not come from the matter. But an important point, which can be seen by [solving the wave equation](https://sites.krieger.jhu.edu/jared-kaplan/files/2016/05/AdSCFTCourseNotesCurrentPublic.pdf), is that particles in $AdS$ behave a lot like particles in a box of volume $L^d$. So writing the energy density as $T_{00} = E / L^d$, the criterion becomes
\begin{align}
E \ll \frac{L^{d - 2}}{G}.
\end{align}
So in a sense, massless scalar fields are the safest. If the field has too large a mass $m$, it is possible for even the lowest excitation (whose energy is just $m$) to already give significant backreaction. For values of $m$ which are small though, the associated primary operators in the CFT with dimension
\begin{equation}
\Delta = \frac{d}{2} \pm \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{d^2 + m^2 L^2}
\end{equation}
will be good candidates for having their correlation functions computed perturbatively from the gravity side. There's a quick sanity check showing that operators which are too heavy really should be thought of as backreacting to create a new geometry. Just take the mass to be $L^{d - 2} / G$ and notice that, up to some order 1 factor, this is the mass of a black hole with a horizon radius of $L$. In the 80s, [Hawking and Page](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01208266) found that black holes growing beyond a size of $L$ undergo a phase transition which makes them no longer evaporate. They come to equilibrium with their own Hawking radiation instead. So this large black hole, being the first stable saddle point besides the AdS vacuum, is a good candidate for what the above operator is creating.

A word of warning though is that, in between the lightest operators with good perturbative dynamics and the heaviest operators which correspond to black holes, there can be several [other regimes](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/709077/string-theory-hilbert-space-gas-of-free-gravitons/710697). Let's solve for $E = m$ in terms of the scaling dimension to write
\begin{equation}
\Delta \ll \frac{L^{d - 1}}{G}
\end{equation}
In the classic example relating $\mathcal{N} = 4$ SYM to type IIB, this says that $\Delta$ is much less than $N^2$ from the gauge group. Abstractly, this is the central charge which becomes the expansion parameter on the CFT side. But, as is well known from that example, holographic computations don't just require $N^2$ to be large to avoid creating black holes (or $N$ to be large to avoid creading branes). They also require a large 'tHooft coupling $\lambda$ because exciting stringy modes becomes possible for dimensionless energies of order $\lambda^{\frac{1}{4}}$. The remarkable thing about this theory is that we don't just have to wave our hands and say that some operator we might never guess has this scaling dimension. Anomalous dimensions for very simple unprotected operators like
\begin{align}
\mathrm{Tr}[\Phi_I \Phi^I]
\end{align}
have been computed and found to agree with $\lambda^{\frac{1}{4}}$. I'm getting off topic though because a bottom-up model found by adding a scalar to AdS doesn't have stringy modes yet. In that case, it should be valid to study scattering processes for descendants at levels below $\frac{L^{d - 1}}{G} - mL$. And it could also be interesting to explicitly seek out backreacting examples like boson stars where the Einstein and Klein-Gordon equations need to be solved together.

Comment: Can you please comment or provide some reference on how the scaling dimension relation you mentioned is modified as the back reaction of the geometry is considered?

Comment: Backreacted geometries correspond to operators with a large scaling dimension. And in this limit, the relation above becomes $\Delta = mL$. This doesn't need to be modified but we need to remember that $m$ is no longer the energy of the lowest excitation for some field in AdS. If it were, the dimension $\Delta$ operator would be dual to that instead of a warped geometry. For the generic case of an operator with a large scaling dimension, we should think of $m$ as being an ADM mass (for a black hole say).

Comment: Heavy operators are becoming more popular these days and https://arxiv.org/abs/2306.15105 is a recent paper exploring them. They derive the equality between a black hole mass and a certain operator's dimension for example in section 3.1.