# Null geodesic equation with affine parameters

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, geodesics

A photon's geodesic equation is defined by re-parameterizing the geodesic equation to some parameter other than proper time. This is done because $ds=0$ for the photon.

Again if we use affine parameter (say $\lambda$) for the path of the null geodesic, we get that the new parameter used is some linear function of proper time.

My question is: If $ds=0$, if the new parameter is linear with proper time,  $d\lambda=0$. Then how can this parameter be used to write the null geodesic.

Comment: For null geodesics, the parameter is not a linear function of proper time.

Comment: Then, how will the re-parameterization be preserve the general form of the geodesic equation?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/17509/

Comment: @0celo7 Then, how will the re-parameterization be preserve the general form of the geodesic equation?

Comment: @TylerHG Sorry sir, I dont think that duplicate quite answers my question

Comment: The geodesic equation guarantees that there exists a $\lambda$ such that it holds. Any parameter related to $\lambda$ then works just as well.