Practical question related to reference frames in general relativity
Sorry if my question requires clarification. I am having trouble conveying exactly what my problem is.
I'm trying to code a ray tracer that works in curved spacetime. In principle, this just entails specifying the metric, calculating the Christoffel symbols, and solving the geodesic equation for the paths the rays of light trace from the camera. However, I'm running into a potential problem.
The issue has to do with the fact that we need to be in the camera's frame of reference before doing the raytracing (I think), since we need to ensure that the rays of light are traced to the appropriate places on the viewing plane and at the appropriate times, according to what the camera would actually see: the times and relative locations at which photons hit the camera depend on what frame we are in, due to loss of simultaneity and length contraction of the viewing plane (in GR, time also works differently in different parts of spacetime due to gravitational effects). For example, two photons that might hit the camera simultaneously in one frame might hit at different times in another and separated by a different distance.
If we were working in special relativity, it would be as simple as Lorentz transforming into a frame moving with the camera before performing the raytracing, but in GR, I am not sure that there even is a corresponding coordinate transformation, since we lack a sense in which we can attach a coordinate system to a local frame of reference. So how can I ensure the image produced on the viewing plane is actually accurate to what the camera would see?
Am I creating a problem where there is none? Could I actually perform the raytracing in an arbitrary coordinate system and get the correct visualization? If yes, how can I be convinced of this?

This may be helpful: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/17509/123208

In my light trajectory diagrams here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/810981/123208 & other linked answers I just use the polar angle $\phi$ in the equatorial plane as my parameter. I've eliminated the Schwarzschild coordinate time from the equations, as described here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/680961/123208 But I guess you can't do that, since you need some kind of time coordinate for your application.


If we were working in special relativity, it would be as simple as Lorentz transforming into a frame moving with the camera before performing the raytracing, but in GR, I am not sure that there even is a corresponding coordinate transformation, since we lack a sense in which we can attach a coordinate system to a local frame of reference.

We can define the reference frame of camera man by an unit time-like vector field $u^a$ in some coordinate system (i.e. $u^au_a=1$). We can think of $u^a$ as the tangent vector on the worldline of the observer (here cameraman). Now, given such a family of observers (note that $u^a=u^a(t,\vec{x})$ varies from one point to another, therefore we can imagine a family of world-lines each having such a timelike vector $u^a$ - aka the timelike congruence of observers), we can define the plane of simultaneity of the camera man as the hypersurface $\Sigma$ such that $u^a$ is orthogonal at each point of intersection. Given that the metric for full spacetime is $g_{ab}$, we can define the induced metric on $\Sigma$ as
$$h_{ab} = g_{ab}-u_au_b$$
You can convince yourself that in Minkowski space-time, a stationary observer ($u^a=(1,0,0,0)$) will correspond to $h_{ab}=diag(-1,-1,-1)$ - the three dimensional Euclidean space. $\Sigma$ will correspond to $t=$constant hypersurfaces.
Now let's say we have family of light rays defined by null vector fields $k^a$, we can define "the relative velocity of light rays as observed by the camera man" , $e^a$ using the following relation:
$$k^a = \Gamma (u^a + e^a)$$
where $u^ae_a=0$, then $\Gamma = u^ak_a$. If you contract both sides of the above equation with $k_a$, you get $e^ae_a=-u^au_a=-1$. Thus, $e^a$ is space-like vector field and has magnitude the same as speed of light.
Given such family of rays with tangent vector $e^a$ in $\Sigma$, we can define the wavefront of such rays as the 2 dimensional surface $N\subset \Sigma$ as the one orthogonal to each ray at their points of intersections. The corresponding induced metric will be
$$s_{ab}=h_{ab}+e_ae_b=g_{ab}-u_au_b+e_ae_b$$
Let's take $X^a$ as the connecting vector between two null rays $k$, then we can take projection of it on the wavefront as $\hat{X}^a={s^a}_bX^b$. This connecting vector could represent the image of some source.
Finally, if the screen of the camera has an unit normal vector $n^a$, then the incident light rays travelling at a relative velocity $e^a$ will subtend an angle $\theta$ as
$$\cos \theta = e^an_a$$
Similar to the definition of wavefront, we can define the induced metric on the screen as
$$q_{ab}=h_{ab}+n_an_b=g_{ab}-u_au_b+n_an_b$$ and the projection of the image $X^a$ on the screen will be $\tilde{X}^a = {q^a}_bX^b$. If $k^a$ is also geodetic, it maybe shown that a change in observer's velocity $u^a$ will only shift $\hat{X}^a$ by some multiple of $k^a$. Also, take any two arbitrary connecting vectors $\hat{X},\hat{Y}$, the quantity $\hat{X}^a\hat{Y}_a$ will remain invariant under change in $u^a$, i.e. shape and size of image on the wavefront of light rays is independent of observer's motion. What can you say about the shape and size of projected images on the camera screen?

Thanks for your reply. Admittedly, I'm struggling a bit to understand this explanation, so I am wondering if you could clarify a few things. In the first paragraph, you mention defining the plane of simultaneity of the cameraman by introducing a family of observers. I'm not quite sure how this family of observers must relate to the cameraman for this definition to make sense. For an inertial cameraman in SR, I can imagine just defining a constant vector field $u^a$ and finding planes orthogonal to this vector, but I can't visualize how this translates to GR.

Second of all, why is the $\Gamma$ factor present in your definition of the relative velocity of the light rays? Does it have to do somehow with these tangent vectors not being parametrized in terms of proper time?

Third, can you clarify exactly what you mean by $X^a$ being a "connecting vector between two null rays"? Naively, it seems like you mean some vector drawn from the intersection of one light ray with $\Sigma$ to the intersection of another with $\Sigma$, but that raises two problems. Firstly, it doesn't specify which two null rays. Secondly, you can't draw a vector between two points in a curved manifold, since they have different tangent spaces. So it must mean something else. Are these two different null rays crossing at the same point in $\Sigma$?

Hi! I'll update my answer addressing your questions later on, here are some short explanations: 1) in SR , you know that all stationary events in a given t=constant plane are simultaneous. Then imagine you replace every such event by the time-like vector orthogonal to the plane. Because it's all smoothly varying, you get a well behaved vector field. And then you consider the integral curves associated to these vector field - these are the worldlines of the observer . Similar argument in GR: you have a spacelike surface Σ and you consider an unit time like vector at each point on it and

consider the integral curves, these are the worldlines of all the observers who are simultaneous wrt the camera man. 2) Yeah u can think of Γ as the equivalent of Lorentz factor if u had considered relative velocity between unit timelike vectors or as the redshift parameter for null vectors. 3) The X^a is supposed to be infinitesimal deviation vector between two adjacent null rays which are integral curves of the k vector. You can integrate it out if u r considering separation between arbitrary far away null trajectories
